# VSTO c#: How to highlight row and column of active cell in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

When I view a large worksheet with numerous data, I  want to highlight the selected cell’ row and column by selecting those particular  row and column.
I don't want to change their background color.
I know how it works in VBA but how for c#?

```
VBA code:

stAreaToMark = stRowToMark + ":" + stRowToMark + "," + stColToMark + ":" + stColToMark;
sh.Range(stAreaToMark).Select;
```